# Simple HTML standards question, DOCTYPE messes the CSS

Tags: html, css, doctype

a very basic question:

When I include the DOCTYPE at the beginning of  my .html document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

It messes only a small part styling of the page.

Here you can see a live example:

[Without DOCTYPE (Right)](http://chaletpuntadeleste.com/)   -    [With DOCTYPE (Wrong)](http://chaletpuntadeleste.com/wrong.php)

I think I kind of "know the answer", (besides that the HTML and CSS seems to be written by a smart chimp), the problem seems to be that some of the elements of the CSS I'm using are not part of the standards of the DOCTYPE I'm using and because of this, some parts are not loaded (in plain English).

That's just me guessing but if this is the case, I would like to know which elements am I using that I should´t and (if specific enough) a "general guide" as to how should they be used.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding px after the 700 in your body style (and everywhere you specify a width in css)

The reason for this is that adding a doctype puts the browser into standards mode (a good thing). You should run your css through a validator to catch errors you get in standards mode.

> Sorry! We found the following errors (5)
>
> **line #**     **Error**
>
> 2     body    Value Error : width only 0
>   can be a length. You must put a unit
>   after your number : 700 700
>
> 18    p.titulo    Property text-shadow
>   doesn't exist in CSS level 2.1 but
>   exists in : 2px 2px 2px #aaa 2px 2px
>   2px #aaa
>
> 140   #rect   Value Error : width only 0
>   can be a length. You must put a unit
>   after your number : 235 235
>
> 151   #form   Value Error : width only 0
>   can be a length. You must put a unit
>   after your number : 235 235
>
> 174   #navcontainer ul    Value Error :
>   margin only 0 can be a length. You
>   must put a unit after your number : 5
>   5

Comment: That is the answer!! So simple! Thank very much!

Comment: @Grills, I definitely will! Thanks agains!

Comment: @Trufa Not a problem. Good luck!

Comment: @Grillz, sorry to bother but what validator did you use? Thanks!!

Comment: W3C http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

Answer (score 2):

The only thing a browser uses the DOCTYPE declaration for is to switch between "Standards Mode" and "Quirks Mode" (and sometimes "Almost Standards Mode"). What it affects is slightly different across browsers.

The main difference (and the biggest one) is that in IE6 it switches between IE's old proprietary CSS Box Model and the "standard" W3C box model which affects how widths and heights are calculated.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_box_model_bug

Unless you know what you're doing you are much better off choosing a DOCTYPE that puts you in Standards Mode

Comment: First time I heard about the Quirks Mode, Thanks for the links I will take a look add some necessary knowledge, (and hopefully will find a suitable DOCTYPE) :)

Answer (score 0):

The CSS for your page is perfectly fine, in the sense that they are valid and correct. Remember that Quirk mode, which is the mode that browsers go into when there's no/invalid `doctype` is IE5.5 mode, what you were really doing before this was to compensate for the semi-broken box model introduced by IE5.5.

Having said that, you might want to clean up your HTML first before moving on to the CSS. The `<b>` tag <del>is officially deprecated</del> are not recommended because they are presentational elements, so you should wrap a `span` around that bit of the title, and giving it a `font-weight: bold` instead.

You should also be using `label`s for your forms. You can then group the `label - input` pairs together using a list.

Finally, as for the title, you can simply remove all the relative positioning, and use `text-align: center`, or, if you need the text to be centered but right aligned, a fixed width and `margin: 0 auto`. Do the same for your main content, and throw away all of the relative positioning and negative margin used to center your content.

Comment: @Yi Jiang, Thanks for taking a look in datil, will definitely correct this issues!!

Comment: @Yi Jiang & @Chris, I could not find any reference as to this, would this mean that the <em> tag is depreciated too?

Comment: @Trufa No, Chris is right. The `<b>` tag was never officially deprecated, unlike the `<s>` or the `<center>` tag. The reason for not using tags like these is simply because HTML is a markup language, and therefore should be used exclusively for content. The `<b>` tag and others like it have no semantic meaning in this context, and there for should not be used. `<em>` and `<strong>` tags on the other hand *do* have meaning - emphasising a particular block of text, and therefore should be used when necessary.

Comment: @Yi Jiang, Thanks for the clarification but I could no really understand the difference, the <b> "emphasizes" too (in plain english), can you think of documentation about this topic in particular? Thanks!!

Comment: @Trufa From the HTML 4.01 Specifications - this is the part about `strong` and `em` tags: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/text.html#h-9.2.1 - you can clearly see that the specification calls for these tags to be used for the emphasis of the text contained in them, while that for the `<b>` tag only states that the text within the tag to be rendered as bold - no special meaning: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/present/graphics.html#h-15.2.1

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-b-element

Comment: @Chris Bad examples given in the specifications - the first would be more semantic if each of those words were wrapped in a `span` with a specific, meaningful class like `rpg-item`, while the second can be **easily** accomplished by dropping a `#article p:first-child` style into the stylesheet - neither truly justify the existence of the `<b>` tag.

Comment: @Yi Jiang, Class names don't add new semantics to HTML and Span has none... But I was not commenting about anybody's usage (or mis-use) of the B element simply pointing to the spec.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the doctype you're using lands you in "limited quirks mode"/"almost standards mode". The right one would be

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

if you insist on XHTML (you shouldn't), or

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

if you insist on an obsolete version (you shouldn't), or

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

if all you need from a doctype is standards mode (it is).